# LeanTouch+ DragUIButton from panel onto 3d gameobject setup?

Tags: unity-game-engine

**LeanTouch+** - I wonder what I need to do to drag UI items onto a 3d object
I couldn't find any example like that in the examples - and would love to have help to achieve it!

UnitySceneSetup:

- Canvas

  - InventoryPanel (panel with canvas group)

    - Key (UIButton)

      - LeanSelectable (component)
      - LeanDraggable (component)
    - Book (UIButton)

      - LeanSelectable (component)
      - LeanDraggable (component)
  - ARCamera (represents the player's view)
- Interactable3DObject (3D GameObject with collider and tag)

  - LeanDrop (component)